# Difference between 'echo' and 'echo -e'

Tags: shell

What is the difference between `echo` and `echo -e`?

And which quotes ("" or '') should be used with the echo command? i.e: `echo "Print statement"` or `echo 'Print statement'`?

Also, what are the available options that can be used along with `echo`?

Comment: What shell? `echo -e` is not defined by POSIX and probably varies by shell.

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo

Comment: use `man echo` to read the manual for `echo`.

Comment: echo doesn't execute its arguments as commands, it just ... echos them

Comment: Also helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/537984/difference-between-echo-e-string-and-echo-string

Comment: It's safe to say that if they're not running a BSD-based distro (including its relatives like Mac), they're probably using GNU utils (where `echo -e` behaves different than `echo`) - which are the default set of programs on all the popular distros like Ubuntu / Debian / CentOS / Arch. That said, `man echo` is the best answer if they're unsure about their particular distribution.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

`echo` by itself displays a line of text. It will take any thing within the following `"..."` two quotation marks, literally, and just print out as it is. However with `echo -e` you're making `echo` to enable interpret backslash escapes. So with this in mind here are some examples

```
INPUT: echo "abc\n def \nghi" 
OUTPUT:abc\n def \nghi

INPUT: echo -e "abc\n def \nghi"
OUTPUT:abc
 def 
ghi
```

Note: `\n` is new line, ie a carriage return. If you want to know what other sequences are recognized by `echo -e` type in `man echo` to your terminal.

Comment: `echo` is built-in in most shells. `man echo` will like document the `echo` standalone command instead.

Comment: You're describing the behaviour of GNU `echo` or the GNU shell's `echo` when not in Unix conformance mode. Elsewhere, the behaviour will typically be different.

Comment: I'd like to encourage the community to upvote this answer with hopes that it will reopen the question. 88-)

Answer (score 18):

In most of the SHELL `echo` cant take **escape sequence** ( `\n \t` ). 
Where as `echo -e` can

`echo -e " This is \n an \t example"`

Single quote and double quote are mostly for handling the interpolation issues. You may find more details here,  [Why is echo ignoring my quote characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24647/why-is-echo-ignoring-my-quote-characters)

Comment: That's the other way round. In most shells (ksh88, ksh93, pdksh, mksh, Bourne, zsh, dash, bash, and the sh of all Unix compliant systems, some of them like ksh93 or bash only in some environments) `echo` does expand escape sequences. An `echo` implementation that accepts `-e` is not POSIX compliant.