# How to use single quotes inside ssh and sqlplus

Tags: shell-script, ssh, quoting

Below script helps me to ssh and do sqlplus to fetch info from database. I checked and it worked well but the only problem is if i use single quotes in the sql query then I am getting an error since I already used single quotes for ssh.

```
db_info=`${ssh_path} -qn ${ssh_host} '
DBHost="<TNS>";
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -s $DBUser/$DBPass@$DBHost <<EOF
set heading off feedback off verify off
Select count(*) from table_name where column = 'hell123';
quit;
EOF
'`
echo $db_info
```

Comment: Try escaping them with backslashes. Something like this: \'hell123\'.

Comment: Use double quotes for the ssh command and then single quotes for the column and for the DBHost. You could also replace the backticks by a `$()` construct.

Comment: `echo 'Like '\'' This'`

Answer (score 2):

You can include a `'` in a single-quoted string by writing `'\''` ([explanation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24647/why-is-echo-ignoring-my-quote-characters/24676#24676)).

But it would be easier to use a here document for the shell snippet to run on the remote host.

```
db_info=$("${ssh_path}" -qn "${ssh_host}" <<\END_SSH
DBHost="<TNS>";
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -s $DBUser/$DBPass@$DBHost <<\END_SQL
set heading off feedback off verify off
Select count(*) from table_name where column = 'hell123';
quit;
END_SQL
END_SSH
)
echo "$db_info"
```

Comment: Thanks Gillies, I already tried this but gettting below error and for your info i am using SunOS.
`Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
stdin: is not a tty
logname: no login name
TERM environment variable not set.
TERM environment variable not set.
Logged out on Thu Jan 7 12:37:23 CET 2016...`

Comment: @JAMUNARANIS Try adding the `-t` option to SSH. This may or may not work, I don't understand why `sqlplus` wants a terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Thrig. I used your idea in my script and it works perfectly. Just add `'\''` in the place of single quote.

```
db_info=`${ssh_path} -qn ${ssh_host} '
DBHost="<TNS>";
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -s $DBUser/$DBPass@$DBHost <<EOF
set heading off feedback off verify off
Select count(*) from table_name where column = '\''hell123'\'';
quit;
EOF
'`
echo $db_info
```